# Is it possilbe to change SLD from client side?

Tags: geoserver, sld

How to change predefile SLD in client side? The reason I want this is I want to turn label on and off on client side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easiest way is to have two SLD files and change the style in the WMS request depending on if you want labels on or off.

Alternatively you could have a separate layer with just labels and turn that on/off as needed.

Or you could try to have a local SLD file and upload it with each request but that will be slower and much harder to handle on the client.

Answer (score 0):

you should look Styled Layer Descriptor (SLD) example on openlayers [here](http://www.openlayers.org/dev/examples/sld.html) about parsing SLD and applying styles to a vector layer of course you will use in openlayers..

i hope it helps you...

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to do the same. I came across the post.

http://underdark.wordpress.com/2010/06/10/dynamic-styling-and-filtering-of-a-geoserver-wms-using-openlayers-layer-wms-post/

Unfortunately, I haven't had luck to make it work.