# Desktop client symbolozing a WMS layer by sending SLD to the WMS server?

Tags: qgis, wms, sld, ogc, udig

Objective is simple: finding 'desktop software' (such as ArcGIS, QGIS, etc) that can load a WMS layer, and then send its own SLD to apply to the WMS server in order to get the WMS layer back with the end-user specified symbology. I haven't found any desktop client that can do that. Any clue?

I am looking for desktop software that can be easily used by non-developers. This software would created SLD, send it to the WMS server and then display the resulting WMS layer with the SLD applied.

I know QGIS 1.8.0 can load/save layers in SLD and that there are plugins expanding SLD capabilities, but I haven't found any way yet to change the symbology of a WMS layer from within QGIS. Thanks! -- Alex

Related questions (which don't answer my specific question):
[How to style a WMS layer?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17527/how-to-style-a-wms-layer)
[Is it possilbe to change SLD from client side?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26631/is-it-possilbe-to-change-sld-from-client-side)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont have any idea about clientside SLD editing. But if you can reach to server you can easyly handle it. I use uDig for this job, Qgis makes problem. For example you have a landuse (polygon type) layer open it with uDig than change style (colors etc.) than export this style as SLD than upload it to your server. I tried this in geoserver with cadastre layer and i succeed.

Comment: What I'm looking for is a client software that will make the request to the WMS server for a layer with the SLD applied. Reason: the users of this WMS server won't have access to the server itself other than via the WMS/SLD standard requests.

Comment: yes its would be perfect, just publish your map with WMS and than people could style it. sounds good. There is a link about ArcGIS server style http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisserver/9.3/java/index.htm#wms_sld.htm    But it says your server SLD must be accesible by users...

Comment: Bingo. Thanks mete7 :) According the to section named "Using external SLDs from the client side" of the page you linked to, it apparently works with ArcGIS 9.3. This page also claims uDig needs the SLD server-side in order for uDig to be able to switch to it.